# Execute code in another users context

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, uac

I have an app with a manifest that requires running as administrator, but part of the app is to map a drive using WNetAddConnection2 which I believe requires it to be run in the normal user context due to credentials etc. Is there a way to execute this bit of code in the normal user context without creating a separate process.

**EDIT**

From the comments I have got this far but it doesnt work. I expected it not to as I dont really understand quite how I should use this. Perhaps it best if I open a new question?

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr hToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr phToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(phToken);
        MapDrives();
        RevertToSelf();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If the current user has admin privileges then the main process is elevated with the manifest, in the code which is elevated I want to run a command in the users non-elevated space as this appears to have different environment variables etc. I believe once a thread is started it cant change itself, it needs to run a new one.

Comment: The way to get the current user authentication token is through WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token. However, I think in your case it will return the token of the administrator user (as your application is running as administrator).

Comment: This is impersonation. A very handy [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/2.0.0) and [the related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/465053) to achieve the same through `LogonUser()` p/invoke call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure this is a way to do this without creating a new process, ImpersonateLoggedOnUser will only work from a service, and I dont want to provide credentials.

correct me if I am wrong

Comment: How do you want to impersonate a user without provide the credentials? I mean would you like to provide only the user name? Or what else?

Comment: If the current user has admin privileges then the main process is elevated with the manifest, in this code which is elevated I want to run a command in the users non-elevated space as this appears to have different environment variables etc. I believe once a thread is started it cant change itself, it needs to run a new one

Comment: This is how you do in-proc impersonation. A very handy [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/2.0.0) and [the related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/465053) to achieve the same through `LogonUser()` p/invoke call.

Answer (score 4):

take a look on [A small C# Class for impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) code project article. It implements an IDisposable class (that releases the authentication token after its use). I've seen .NET code leaking due to not releasing the impersonation tokens.

You can impersonate a user only for a block of code that will access the network resource you need to access as a different user. Your code will look like

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
   /* code that executes under the new context */
   ...
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to obtain the user token that you want to start the app as, you can do this using [WTSQueryUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(VS.85).aspx).   If the user is not yet logged on you can use [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API to obtain a new one in a new session.  To get all the sessions on your computer you can use [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(v=VS.85).aspx).

Then once you have the token you can use [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx) or else [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612(VS.85).aspx) Win32 APIs.

Please make sure to call `CloseHandle` on the handles you obtain, they are especially bad leaks for this type of work.

Comment: Please don't forget to mention to call the CloseHandle function after finished to use the token returned by LogonUser function. If you don't do this you can have an operating system level handle leak. I've seen this happen before.

Comment: @Carlos: Ditto they are especially bad leaks too.  I added a comment about that.

Comment: Arent both CreateProcessAsUser and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser used to create a new thread with different credentials? How do I get WNetAddConnections2 to run in this new process?

Comment: @Charles: CreateProcessAsUser creates a new process as the specified user.  ImpersonateLoggedOnUser executes the code within the same process and thread.  WNetAddConnections2 is for something entirely different, authenticating yourself with a LAN machine or other resource.

Comment: So what I want is my WNetAddConnections2 function to be called using ImpersonateLoggedOnUser ?

Comment: @Charles: Yes or within a new process you create using CreateProcessAsUser.